# Importing nco package: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, package, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I'm trying to use the nco package to merge multiple netcdf files using ncrcat. This in itself is easy to do, but I'm unable to get past the second line:

```
from nco import Nco
nco=Nco()

mrms1= nc.Dataset("/Users/arian/project/data/mrms_20190501/20190501_190000.nc")
mrms2= nc.Dataset("/Users/arian/project/data/mrms_20190501/20190501_190500.nc")

nco.ncrcat(input=[mrms1, mrms2], output='testnet.nc')
```

Where the nco=Nco() gives the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Ordinarly I know this error arises when you try to get the length from nothing, but from what I understand this instance has to be created in order to use ncrcat in the script.

I made sure an updated version of both nco and pynco is on anaconda. I also tried using the cdo package to merge the files the files instead, but I get the same error. I've also used ncrcat as a command line in the terminal, but I get a "term is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" so that's a separate can of worms. Also, netCDF4.MFDataset doesn't work because the data doesn't have  time dimension to aggregate, nor does xarray, which gives a TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Dataset found.

Based on many hours of research, I feel the nco len() Typerror is the easiest to fix, but all help from anything I mentioned is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I've also used ncrcat as a command line in the terminal, but I get a "term is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" so that's a separate can of worms." < I've got a feeling the answer lies here. You should be able to run something from the NCO ecosystem in your terminal, right? I'm guessing the fact that it's not recognised in PATH is a clue. What OS are you using?

Comment: @PeptideWitch I'm on Windows 10, and I'm used to using Linux which has worked when I imported this package before, so you're probably right. By NCO ecosystem, do you mean the location where the package is installed, correct? Unfortunately, even running from that location gives the same "term is not recognized" error, even if I list out the full netcdf file paths

Comment: You might have to edit the environment variables so that when you type the command into your terminal, the command prompt knows which directory to search. In addition, check out 1.3.1 and 1.5 from http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#Windows-Operating-System . Perhaps `LD_LIBRARY_PATH ` needs to be edited in environment variables to point to your install?

Comment: @PeptideWitch Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly even trying this didn’t work, so I uninstalled and installed again but to no prevail. Maybe I’m not meant to use this package haha. But it also has ensemble averaging compabilities which I could really really use.

Comment: I know the feeling! Have you had previous success with this package on a linux system? Maybe it would be worth trying this on a virtualbox linux distribution

Comment: @PeptideWitch Yup I used it on the Linux system on my computer at school, but since the school shut down from COVID I converted completely to my laptop. But I can try downloading a Virtualbox! The only thing is my laptop has only a few GB of space left...this is something I can download on a flash drive right?

Comment: I think that's possible! [This seems to be how you go about it](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/). Grab virtualbox, grab a linux distro you like, make a virtual hard disk (your USB) and install to that

Comment: Alternatively, you cqan install linux onto a USB and then set up a bootloader to give you the option to boot from USB. No need for virtualbox

Comment: Ok I'll try it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: A couple of quick points
1) The Input argument should be  a string of a  filename or a list of string filenames  

2) I am no expert on conda but if you want to  run pynco you need the nco commands in your PATH  environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points

1) input must be a string of a filename or a list of strings of filenames 
   e.g   input =["20190501_190000.nc", "20190501_190500.nc"]

2)  I am no expert on conda but to run pynco the nco commands must be in your PATH environment variable